# Distribute all rows in Each Months Mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new to mysql

```
Address        Type    MonthCreated       YearCreated
AddA1           M1     August                 2018
AddA1           I2     August                 2018
AddA1           K2     October                2018
```

Desired Output
is like this three rows will be distrubuted in every month like to january february march to december 2018

```
Select  AddA1,Type,MonthCreated,YearCreated 
from tbltry 
where YearCreated = '2018'
```

Desired Output is all the rows for each month since it is still in the same year I am just wondering if its possible really need help or advice

```
Address        Type    MonthCreated       YearCreated
AddA1           M1     January                2018
AddA1           I2     January                2018
AddA1           K2     January                2018
AddA1           M1     February               2018
AddA1           I2     February               2018
AddA1           K2     February               2018
AddA1           M1     March                  2018
AddA1           I2     March                  2018
AddA1           K2     March                  2018
```

up till december it will returns all the rows is it possible? Really need advice

Comment: Not clear to me what you are asking!

Comment: You can create a master table for months, and use that to join to produce the remaining rows.

Comment: like is it possible to distribute the three rows for each month january to december because when I want to show all the rows from tbltry it will show three rows I wanted this three rows to be distributed for every month january to december

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can create a "Master Table" for all the months.
- In another Derived table, you can get the distinct combinations of `AddA1` and `Type` for the year 2018.
- Simply do a `CROSS JOIN` between them to get all possible months.

Try:

```
SELECT dttry.*, all_months.*
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT AddA1, Type, YearCreated
 FROM tbltry 
 WHERE YearCreated = '2018') AS dttry
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT 'January' AS MonthCreated UNION ALL
 SELECT 'February' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'March' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'April' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'May' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'June' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'July' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'August' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'September' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'October' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'November' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'December') AS all_months
```